# How to query documents where contains an array and the value of the array is ["val1", "val2"] Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get a collection where the query should be applicable to an array inside the document.

Document example: I would like to know how to query the document where the brands are `fiat` and `seat`

```
{
   "name":"test 1",
   "brands":[
      {
         "brand":{
            "id":1,
            "name":"Fiat",
            "slug":"fiat",
            "image":null,
            "year_end":null,
            "year_start":null
         },
         "released_at":"2018-10-26"
      },
      {
         "brand":{
            "id":2,
            "name":"Seat",
            "slug":"seat",
            "image":null,
            "year_end":null,
            "year_start":null
         },
         "released_at":"2018-10-26"
      },
      {
         "brand":{
            "id":3,
            "name":"Mercedes",
            "slug":"mercedes",
            "image":null,
            "year_end":null,
            "year_start":null
         },
         "released_at":"2018-10-26"
      },
      {
         "brand":{
            "id":4,
            "name":"Yamaha",
            "slug":"yamaha",
            "image":null,
            "year_end":null,
            "year_start":null
         },
         "released_at":"2018-10-26"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried something like:

```
.collection("motors")
.where("brands.slug", "array-contains-any", ["fiat", "seat"])
```

but this is not working I cannot figure out by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) how to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `array-contains-any` operator, you can check the values of your array against the value of a property of type String and **not** an array. There is currently no way you can use `array-contains-any` operator on an array. There are two options, one would be to create two separate fields and create two separate queries or, been only a document, you can get the entire document and filter the data on the client.

**Edit:**

What @FrankvanPuffelen has commented is correct, I made some research and I found that we can check against any type and even complex types, not just against strings, as mentioned before. The key to solving this issue is to match the entire object, meaning all properties of that object and not just a partial match, for example, one of three properties.

What you are trying to achieve is not working with your current database structure because your `slug` property exists in an object that is nested within the actual object that exists in your array. A possible solution might also be to duplicate some data and add only the desired values into an array and use the `array-contains-any` operator on this new creatded array.

Comment: Hey Alex. You can actually check against any type and even complex types, not just against strings. But you must check against the full value of the item in the array, not against a partial match. So your solution is correct, but can you clarify why what they want isn't possible with their current data structure?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey puf. Yes, you're right. I just updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo so the idea I'm having to solve this is create a new property in the documents, something like "brandNames":["Fiat", "Seat", "Audi"] to be able to look for this.. is the best solution I can find. now my problem is I have more than 400.000 documents so.. any idea how to update all of the to create a new property "brandNames " from "brands".

Comment: Creating an array is a good idea to go ahead with. If you need to update 400.000 documents then you should consider using [batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). But please note that there is a limitation of 500 operations per batch. Another option would be to [export your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import), make the update and upload it back to the server.